Finding the bounding circle
The logic in my code is not absolute. I tried to find the center coordinates and radius of bounding circle by taking the diameter end points as 1) the point farthest from origin and 2) the point farthest away from (1).
But this is does not give me an actual result in all cases.
pls dont mind indendation (I use tabs and copied my code.)
from tkinter import *

class point2D:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
    
    def x(self):
        return self.__x
    
    def y(self):
        return self.__y
    
    def setx(self, x):
        self.__x = x
    
    def sety(self, y):
        self.__y = y
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.__x}, {self.__y})"
    
    def distance(self, other):
        return ((self.__x-other.__x)**2 + (self.__y-other.__y)**2) ** 0.5

class box:
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.title("Bounding Circle")
        width, height = 600, 600
        root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")
        
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.addpoint)
        
        self.origin = point2D()
        
        self.points = []
        
        root.mainloop()
    
    def addpoint(self, event):
        radius = 5
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x - radius, event.y - radius,
        event.x + radius, event.y + radius, fill = "black")
        self.points.append(point2D(event.x, event.y))
        self.getboundingcircle()
    
    def getboundingcircle(self):
        if len(self.points) == (1 or 0):
            return
        #Finding the point farthest from origin (0,0 in canvas)
        d, start = self.points[0].distance(self.origin), 0
        for i in range(1, len(self.points)):
            x = self.points[i].distance(self.origin)
            if x > d:
                d = x
                start = i
        #Finding the point farthest from points[start]
        d, end = 0, 0
        for i in range(len(self.points)):
            if i == start:
                continue
            x = self.points[i].distance(self.points[start])
            if x > d:
                d = x
                end = i
        
        center_x = (self.points[start].x() + self. points[end].x()) / 2
        center_y = (self.points[start].y() + self. points[end].y()) / 2
        radius = self.points[start].distance(self.points[end]) / 2
        
        self.canvas.delete("circle")
        self.canvas.create_oval(center_x - radius, center_y - radius,
        center_x + radius, center_y + radius, outline = "red", tags = "circle")

box()


Your bounding circle should just have a radius equal to the distance of your furthest point from the origin to ensure it encloses all points.

Or, find the centroid of all you points and calculate the distance from that and use that as the radius of a bounding circle with the centroid as origin.

What restrictions are there on your circle, @Adwaidh Chandran A ? Can its centre be anywhere? Do you want the minimum-radius circle? (The latter must go through at least two points).

I want a minimum-radius circle.

This question may help.

Here is an example that you could adapt (I've based it to include your point2D class, but I've also used numpy for simplicity with commented out equivalents if numpy can't be used):
class point2D:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
    
    def x(self):
        return self.__x
    
    def y(self):
        return self.__y
    
    def setx(self, x):
        self.__x = x
    
    def sety(self, y):
        self.__y = y
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.__x}, {self.__y})"
    
    def distance(self, other):
        return ((self.__x-other.__x)**2 + (self.__y-other.__y)**2) ** 0.5
    

class points:
    """
    Class to store multiple point2D objects.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._points = []

    def append(self, point: point2D):
        if not isinstance(point, point2D):
            raise TypeError("point must be a point2D object")
        
        self._points.append(point)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return np.array([p.x() for p in self._points])
        # return [p.x() for p in self._points]
    
    @property
    def y(self):
        return np.array([p.y() for p in self._points])
        # return [p.y() for p in self._points]
    
    @property
    def xy(self):
        return np.vstack((self.x, self.y)).T
        # return [(x, y) for x, y in zip(self.x, self.y)]
    
    @property
    def mean(self):
        # return x, y coordinates of the mean of all point
        return self.xy.mean(axis=0)
        # return [sum(self.x) / len(self), sum(self.y) / len(self)]
    
    @property
    def bounding_radius(self):
        # return the maximum distance of all points from the mean
        return np.max(np.linalg.norm(self.xy - self.mean, axis=1))
        # m = self.mean
        # r = 0
        # for rv in [((xy[0] - m[0])**2 + (xy[1] - m[1])**2)**0.5 for xy in self.xy]:
        #     if rv > r:
        #         r = rv
        # return r

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._points)


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

# add some points
p = points()
p.append(point2D(3, 4))
p.append(point2D(-1, -5))
p.append(point2D(-0.4, 3.2))
p.append(point2D(5.4, -2.1))

# get the mean and maximum distance from the mean
m = p.mean
r = p.bounding_radius

# in your code you could have
# center_x = m[0]
# center_y = m[1]
# radius = p.bounding_radius

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(p.x, p.y)
ax.plot(m[0], m[1], 'kx')
ax.add_artist(Circle(m, r, ec="r", fc=None, fill=False))
ax.set_xlim([m[0] - r, m[0] + r])
ax.set_ylim([m[1] - r, m[1] + r])
ax.set_aspect("equal")



Centroid guarantees a properly bounding circle, but doesn't necessarily generate the smallest circle. Consider a 1D example where points are more lopsided to the right-most point e.g. [0, 10, 8]. This would generate a circle at center 6 with radius 6 rather than a smaller circle at center 5 with radius 5. This still answers the question, but I wanted to leave this caveat.

Yes, that's certainly true. It's not clear if the questioner want the smallest possible bounding circle or not. Of course you could also create a smaller bounding ellipse, if the circle requirement is not enforced and it can be rotated.

I wonder if starting with the center of the bounding box would lead to a better result?

Inside the linked question in my comment, user @Nayuki has provided smallestenclosingcircle.py to get the bounding circle of points.  There is a modified module in pypi.org based on @Nayuki code that you can install and use in your code.
Below is a simplified example based on your code:
import tkinter as tk
from smallestenclosingcircle import make_circle, is_in_circle

class Box(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Bounding Circle')

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=600, height=600, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.add_point)

        self.points = []
        self.circle = None

    def add_point(self, event):
        radius = 5
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-radius, event.y-radius,
                                event.x+radius, event.y+radius, fill='black')
        point = (event.x, event.y)
        self.points.append(point)
        if (len(self.points) > 1) and not is_in_circle(self.circle, point):
            self.get_bounding_circle()

    def get_bounding_circle(self):
        x, y, radius = self.circle = make_circle(self.points)
        print(f'{x:.2f}, {y:.2f}, {radius:.2f}')
        self.canvas.delete('circle')
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius, outline='red', tags='circle')

Box().mainloop()

Result:


I think may be modifying the getboundingcircle function inside the box class may do what you want. I don understand well if this is the expected behavior but it's one possible behavior.
You should import math at the beginning:
from tkinter import *
import math

And then replace your current function:
def getboundingcircle(self):
    if len(self.points) < 2:
        return

    # Find the two farthest points
    max_dist = 0
    start, end = 0, 1  # Initialize start and end

    for i in range(len(self.points)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(self.points)):
            dist = self.points[i].distance(self.points[j])
            if dist > max_dist:
                max_dist = dist
                start = i
                end = j

    center_x = (self.points[start].x() + self.points[end].x()) / 2
    center_y = (self.points[start].y() + self.points[end].y()) / 2
    radius = self.points[start].distance(self.points[end]) / 2

    self.canvas.delete("circle")
    self.canvas.create_oval(center_x - radius, center_y - radius,
                           center_x + radius, center_y + radius, 
                           outline="red", tags="circle")


I tried a similar approach but found that this does not work in all cases. While all point to point distances are shorter than the diameter, the line from point to point does not have to go through the center, therefore, you can have "chords" that must breach outside the circle. Consider the case [(0, 0), (10, 0), (5, 6)].

@michael-cao: That is kind of obvious, then he should the implement the Welzl algorithm but it's more complex than this simpler approaches. There's one implementation here. Then he could make a recursive approach. To use an arbitrary centroid will not resolve the problem.
